# C# Convert listbox item to double

Tags: c#, string, listbox, double

I´m trying to convert a `listbox.item` in a foreach to a double but it will not work:

```
foreach (string row in listBoxOperation1.Items)
{
    double x = Convert.ToDouble(row);
}
```

I have also tried `Double.Parse` and `Double.TryParse` but always return: The input string had an incorrect format.

If I add:

```
listBoxProgram.Items.Add(row);
```

It gives these following values:

```
3999.0
3333.33
1111.11
666.66
```

Comment: Well, what's the input string?  What *specifically* is `row`?  If it's an object, what does `row.ToString()` give you?

Comment: Just a guess, it can be related to the Culture, try `InvariantCulture` with `Double.TryParse`.

Comment: you use listBoxOperation1 in foraeach whereas listBoxProgram for add. Is this intended??

Comment: row.ToString() give the same error.
The input should be a string, it reads from a text file in to a listbox and then I try to use these values and sort them out for different purposes.
Only dots are used, its not a problem to convert a textbox.text with the same value to double

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you have added them as `double` you just need to cast them:

```
double x = (double) row;
```

If you have addded them as strings, maybe you don't use `.` as decimal separator but `,`. Provide the correct `CultureInfo`, for example `en-US`:

```
CultureInfo usCult = new CultureInfo("en-US");
double x;
string numberStr = (string) row;
bool validNumber = double.TryParse(numberStr, NumberStyles.Any, usCult, out x);
```

if the format was invalid the `validNumber` will be `false`, otherwise `x` will  contain the value.

Comment: Thank you very much! this solved it.
I added also using System.Globalization;

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing. If the row is of type `System.Data.DataRow`, then of course you cannot convert it to `double`. `DataRow` is not convertible to `double`. You would first have to get the value stored in a specifc column

```
foreach (DataRow row in listBoxOperation1.Items) {
    object obj = row["MyColumn"];
    ...
}
```

Now if the item is of type double, you can just cast it:

```
var d = (double)obj;
```

If it is of type string, you need to convert it to double

```
if (Double.TryParse((string)obj, out double d)) {
    // We have a double d.
} else {
    // Something went wrong (e.g. the column is empty).
}
```

In any case, the type of `row` in this line is essential:

```
listBoxProgram.Items.Add(row); // Of which type is 'row'?
```

Comment: It's a ListBox, the row is an object. If this object was a `DataRow` the listbox would display `System.Data.DataRow` for every item because `DataRow` doesn't override `ToString`.

Comment: I get to var "row = (DataRow)item;" and then I get the errror "Cannot convert system.String to System.DataRow"
I´m a somewhat newbie in C# just so you know.

Comment: The items you retrive from `listBoxOperation1.Items` in the foreach-loop have the same type as the ones you added to it with `listBoxProgram.Items.Add(row);`. Therefore we need to know how you declared the `row` variable in `listBoxProgram.Items.Add(row);`. Which type does `row` have? Please show us the declaration of `row`. Is it `double row;` or `string row;` or `DataRow row` or something else?

Comment: They where added as strings, however, the problem was with the decimal separator as stated in the answer above.
For some reason its a problem in the foreach loop and listbox, I have no problem with this in textboxes.